# Scheduled GCE VM instance startup and shutdown

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using GCE for a small R&D project with limited budget. We would like to be able to start/stop instances automatically on a schedule e.g. to run VM instances during office hours but shut them down out of hours to save costs. As far as I can tell, there is no instance scheduler in the current GCE toolset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Zorya - open source Google Compute Engine instance scheduler.

Blog: https://blog.doit-intl.com/reduce-google-compute-engine-costs-by-60-with-zorya-gce-instance-scheduler-eae07131cafa

GitHub: https://github.com/doitintl/zorya

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google App Engine(GAE) to make a cron job to start/shutdown your GCE instance.
Refer [Scheduling Cron Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron) how to configure your cron job.

Please do note GAE will cost you for the usage as well, but there is  [free usage](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits) for GAE as well, which you might be able to utilize.