# Schedule GCE VM to automatically stop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to schedule an auto shutdown of Compute Engine instance at specific time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use command line [gcloud tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/stop) or [Google Compute API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/stop) to stop a GCE instance. You can implement any of that method and schedule it using cron job.

Comment: I found some additional community suggestion [1,2] which might be helpful.
[1] https://serverfault.com/questions/873229/scheduled-gce-vm-instance-startup-and-shutdown
[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875480/can-google-compute-instances-be-started-and-stopped-on-a-schedule